# Finding item in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I'm coming from C# and LINQ is like second nature. I have following function and I wonder if section where I "skip" special attributes can be shortened? I have array of attribute "names" and I'd like to return list of attributes from self.attributes which DO NOT contain those names. This is my function and this would be 1 line in C# :(

```
- (NSArray*)getDisplayedAttributes
{
    //Get stop attributes
    NSMutableArray *attributes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (Attribute *attr in self.attributes)
    {
        // Skip special attribute
        BOOL found = false;
        for (Attribute *sa in @[@"D:AR",@"D:AS",@"D:ARF",@"D:DD",@"D:DH"])
        {
            if ([(NSString*)sa isEqualToString:attr.name])
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (found) continue;

        Attribute *attribute = [[Attribute alloc] init];
        attribute.name = attr.name;
        attribute.value = attr.value;        
        [attributes addObject:attribute];
    }

    return attributes;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of sample input and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a one-liner in Objective-C too

```
- (NSArray*)getDisplayedAttributes
{
    return [self.attributes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT name IN %@",@[@"D:AR",@"D:AS",@"D:ARF",@"D:DD",@"D:DH"]]];
}
```

although it's one long line :)

Note that this code returns the same `Attribute` objects as in the original array, it doesn't create new ones, like in your code. If you want the filtered array to contain clones of the original attributes, then you need to implement the `copy` method on `Attribute`.

Comment: Yes, I will need copies, but it's OK as I need to do more to those new copies. Code above is exactly what I was looking for. Just learning my way around..

Comment: @Rob thanks for noticing that, I corrected my answer. I should stop wrtting code directly in the SO editor :P

Comment: By the way, rather than implementing `copy`, I'd suggest implementing `copyWithZone` instead and then conform to `NSCopying`. Then, the object will not only respond to `copy` automatically, but you can also do thing like copy an array of `Attribute` objects with `[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: copy:]`, too.

Comment: Yeah, I initially wanted to mention about NSCopying and `initiWithArray:copyItems:`, but I felt I'd give too much information within an answer.